# Cannot override a rule, even when using !important

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-cascade

I must be overseeing something or have some stupid error in my code, but I can't override Class CSS with the ID CSS AND ( *blush* ) even with adding the loathed !important hack ...

NB: This is a old(ish) WordPress template, still using clearing div for floats, but I have to work with it. Not my choice.

HTML:

```
<body id="page-front-page" class="page-template-homepage">

<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gardens</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="sidebar">
blah
</div>
```

CSS

```
#page-front-page > .sidebar {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0 !important;
width: 45%;
}
```

few lines further is

```
.sidebar {
width: 280px;
padding: 50px 40px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
font-size: 0.71em;
font-family: 'BrandonGrotesque-Light';
}
```

I've even tried swapping places of respective .sidebar CSS , but nothing helps. Simply cannot get  `right:0;` to override `left:0;`.

Here is the inspector screenshot:

[image: Screenshot sidebar CSS]

What am I missing, not seeing, being dumb about? 
Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has to do with "specifity": The overriding rule's selector has to be at least as specific as the other one, so you have to use this selector on the second rule:

```
#page-front-page > .sidebar {
```

(google for "CSS specifity" to learn about the exact importance of the different parts of a selector concerning specifity )

Addition: Yes, and as Michael_B and BoltClock wrote, you can't override a `right` parameter with a `left` parameter, but have to reset the first one to `auto`

Comment: This has nothing to do with specificity, for the very reason given in Michael_B's answer. Your addendum serves to disprove the rest of your answer.

Comment: @BoltClock concerning those parameters which are in both rules, like `padding` and `width` (which is less obvious since you don't see it immediately), it also HAS to do with specifity - width and padding won't change to the values of the second rule if you don't use the full selector I put in my answer. See this codepen where I added a background color to the first rule, but left everything else like in the OPs code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWOogV Add the the full selector to the second rule and you see what I am talking about

Answer (score 2):

You would use `right 0 !important` to override another `right` declaration. You're using it in an attempt to override another property. That's not how it works. There's no connection because they're two different properties.

If you want the opposite of `left: 0`, then try `left: 100%`... or, as @BoltClock mentioned in the comments, `left: auto`.

Comment: The opposite of left: 0 in this case, I suspect, is left: auto.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
  #page-front-page > .sidebar {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0 !important;
    width: 45%;
    left:inherit!important;
    }
```